# PHP: trying make ajax call from foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php

I am looping through data form a database to a form that makes a Ajax request to add an item to a shopping basket/cart. Everything works fine except that only the first item in the array is added? I have tried using classes as apposed to id's(unique

```html
echo "<div class='col-100 border-temp bg-orange'>"; 
echo "<div class='col-50 border-temp'>"; 

foreach ($result as $key => $result) { 
  $m = $result["model_no"]; 
  $q = $result["qty_available"]; 
 
  echo "<form method='post' action='/stock-clearance' class='stock_clearance bg-blue'>"; 
  echo "<label for='model_no'><h2>Model No</h2></label>"; 
  echo "<input id='model_no' name='model' type='text' placeholder='Paste model no... ' value='$m' />"; 
  echo "<span id='model_error'></span>"; 
  echo "<label for='quantity'>Quantity</label><br />"; 
  echo "<input id='quantity' name='quantity' value='1' type='number' min='1' max='$q'>"; 
  echo " <span id='quantity_error'></span>"; 
  //echo "<input id='sc_add_to_cart' name='' value='$key' type='button'>"; 
  echo "<input id='sc_add_to_cart' name='sc_add_to_cart' value='Add to Basket' type='submit'>"; 
  echo "</form>"; 
} // End foreach loop 
echo "</div>";
```

)
My JS code is as follows:

```js
$('#sc_add_to_cart').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('.stock_clearance');
        hideStockClearanceMessages(form);

        var request = $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() { form.css({ opacity: 0.4 }); },
            url: 'ajax.php',
            cache: 'false',
            data: {
                action: "sc-add-to-cart",
                model: $('input[name="model"]').val(),
                quantity: $('input[name="quantity"]').val()
            }
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0irt.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can not have the same one ID for a different inputs. ID must be UNIQUE. Instead of ID use CLASS attribute

Answer (score 0):

1- Sometimes because of caching problem it will not work so you have to add seed to your call.

- [seedrandom()](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom)

```js
function seed() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
}

$('#sc_add_to_cart').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('.stock_clearance');
        hideStockClearanceMessages(form);

        var request = $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() { form.css({ opacity: 0.4 }); },
            url: 'ajax.php?sid=' + seed(),
            cache: 'false',
            data: {
                action: "sc-add-to-cart",
                model: $('input[name="model"]').val(),
                quantity: $('input[name="quantity"]').val()
            }
        });
```

2. Please use `ID`s only for one element. They must be unique. You can use `CLASS` instead.